# When will this terminate?

Tags: agda

I actually want to prove one theorem but i think if I prove on the other side that is fine also.

I have defined a stream of positive rationals like this:

```
one : ℤ
one = + 1

next : pair → pair
next q = if (n eq one) then (mkPair (+ m Data.Integer.+ one) 1)
         else (mkPair (n Data.Integer.- one) (m Nat.+ 1))
  where
     n = getX q
     m = getY q

-- eq is defined correctly for equivalence of two integer. 
rational : Stream pair
rational = iterate next (mkPair one 1) 

RQ : pair → Stream pair → Stream pair
RQ q (x ∷ xs) = (x add q) ∷ ♯ (RQ q (♭ xs))    

positiveRat : Stream pair
positiveRat = RQ (mkPair (+ 0) (1)) rational
```

Here `pair` is a record with ℤ and ℕ fields:

```
 --records of rational number
record pair : Set where
  field
    x : ℤ
    y : ℕ

mkPair : ℤ → ℕ → pair
mkPair a b = record { x = a; y = b}
```

Now I want to prove that *every rational which is in `positiveRat` will be positive*.

```
open import Data.Stream
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Rational
open import Data.Integer
open import Coinduction
open import Data.Unit

lemma : (x : pair) → (x ∈ positiveRat) → (+ 0 Data.Integer.≤ pair.x x)
lemma .(record { x = + 1 ; y = 1 }) here = +≤+ z≤n
lemma .(record { x = + 2 ; y = 1 }) (there here) = +≤+ z≤n
lemma .(record { x = + 1 ; y = 2 }) (there (there here)) = {!!}
lemma q (there (there (there pf))) = {!!}
```

I am writing the proof by splitting on `pf`. But it is unstoppable.

Comment: Updated code is missing imports and other auxiliary definitions. Make sure your code is typecheckable as-is.

Comment: import are the same with the second part above the lemma. and i have given other definition as well now.

Comment: I don't see 'ans' defined

Comment: That was "rational". I have updated. Please check.

Comment: You need to change your code snippet to be self-contained. Basically, the code snippet needs to be copy-able into an empty file as-is and typecheck with Agda (modulo the missing case of `lemma` of course).

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to solve on this mock example because `stream` is periodic:

```
lemma : (x : ℚ) → (x ∈ stream) → (+ 0 Data.Integer.≤ ℚ.numerator x)
lemma .(record { numerator = + 1}) here = +≤+ z≤n
lemma .(record { numerator = + 2}) (there here) = +≤+ z≤n
lemma .(record { numerator = + 3}) (there (there here)) = +≤+ z≤n
lemma q (there (there (there pf))) = lemma q pf
```

However, I imagine in your real example, `stream` is not periodic. There is no generic answer; the correct proof of `lemma` depends on how your real `stream` is defined, so you will have to post that.

Comment: @ajayv but that's exactly my point -- you will need to post your real code defining `stream` (how you enumerate all positive rationals) for that question to be answerable.

Comment: I have updated the problem by showing how i represented the stream of positive rational. I have one other question can you give me some hint how will i prove that  `lemma : (x : ℚ) → ( (+ 0 Data.Integer.≤ ℚ.numerator x) → (x ∈ stream)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951993/how-to-resolve-this-error-in-agda This is my original problem which i want to ask but dint get answer. Please help me this too Sir.